# include_path related problems in php

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have a PHP application where the autoloader is situated in `/var/www/html/example.com/src/vendors/autoloader.php`

```
var/
  www/
    html/
      example.com
        app/
        vendors/
          vendor_a/
           example.php
          vendor_b/
          vendor_c/
          autoloader.php
        public/
```

In `autoloader.php` I have a line that requires `example.php` from the `vedor_a/` folder.
although this works in my local virtual box running centos, php-fpm, nginx it fails to work in my vps, which has the same version of every program I am running in my localhost.

I am using php5.5.14

and I get this error when I require the above file.

Warning: require(vendor_a/example.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/example.com/vendors/autoloader.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor_a/example.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/example.com/vendors/autoloader.php on line 2

I haven't modified anything from my `php.ini` where the `include_path` defaults to

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
```

I am looking more than a solution here. Because I can see the `include_path` looks for `php/includes` dir when constructs such as `require`, `include`, `include_once`... at-least [according to the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) but I can't find a directory called `php/includes` so why is that setting even there?

Comment: It looks like the php.ini you're examining is not the one PHP is using, because the error indicates include_path is `.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php` but the `.` at the beginning means it is correctly checking the current working directory first. Check the output of `phpinfo()` to see the path of the php.ini that is actually loaded.

Comment: You have no code which changes the working directory via `chdir()`? Just before the `require('vendor_a/example.php');` assuming that is how your line looks, `echo getcwd();` to see where PHP thinks it is executing in your filesystem at the time you attempt to include from vendor_a.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It's correct I can see `Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php.ini `

Comment: Ooohh I misread your pasted fragment from php.ini.  It isn't actually using `.:/php/includes`, that is commented out with `;`. That is just be a default example in the distro's php.ini (I have it too) and the following line describes what the default path is (which is the path your error message indicates)

Comment: So your include path is indeed `include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php'`

Comment: You should be able to successfully use `require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor_a/example.php');` but it would be better to figure out why PHP isn't finding that directory in the current working dir.

Comment: Ok. I have been trying, but still the same error. Then only thing that has changed is that I can see the file's (example.php) full path in the error. Are you sure the `include_path` value should be `'.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php'`? Because my application is found in `/var/www/html/` folder

Comment: The `.` at the start means to look in the current directory, so you don't need `/var/www/html` in the include path. If you see the full path expanded in the include and PHP still doesn't find the file, that's a pretty strong indicator that the file doesn't actually exist, or possibly the file exists but is not readable by PHP. verify that the `vendor_a` directory and its contents don't have 700/600 permissions whereby PHP would not be able to read them. The `vendor_a` needs to be other-readable and executable (chmod 755 vendor_a) and its contents should be something like 644.

Comment: did you manage to fix this?